# Search in pcap faster then normal

Tags: python, python-3.x, scapy, pcap

```
packets = rdpcap("/home/pcap_evidence/"+date+"/"+list_time[0]+"")
for data in packets:
   if IP in data:
      if data[IP].src == ip and data[IP].dst == ip:
        list_.append(data)
```

In this code i am reading a pcap using rdpcap and then iterating it using for loop by this way i am getting row wise data of packets and on evry pcaket i am searching for a particular ip and if ip matchs with any src_ip or dst_ip then storing that pcaket and making a new filtered pcap.

And all this takes 5 mins for searching a 600 mb of file and i want to do it alot faster then that. how can i do it.

Comment: How long does it take in Wireshark?

Comment: at least, iterate through `PcapReader` instead of using `rdpcap`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

scapy in known to be slow. I would avoid scapy for big files.

the best way, is to use tshark
exemple:

```
tshark -r my_capture.pcap -Y "(ip.src == 192.168.1.10) && (ip.dst == 172.27.224.70)" -w /tmp/my_filtered_capture.pcap
```

If you need the result in python, you can call that then parser the result after.

Comment: tshark is cool but if you need this to be fast, tcpdump should be your first choice. It's orders of magnitude faster than tshark for filters it can express. I just ran a quick comparison of a host-pair filter on a 125MB pcap, and tcpdump is about 50x faster with comparable options.